# Python with -c flag, input from user and if/else inside - shows syntax error

Tags: python

I need a simple one-liner in Python: ask user for choice and then print a message depending on what user chose. Here's my attempt:

`python3 -c "ans=input('Y/N?'); if ans == 'Y': print('YES') else: print('NO');"`

And errors of course:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    ans=input('Y/N?'); if ans == 'Y': print('YES') else: print('NO');
                       ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is it possible to do this in one-liner? It must be one-liner, I can't use a script here. Thanks.

Comment: why must it be on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution of your question

```
python3 -c "ans=input('Y/N?'); print('YES') if ans == 'Y'  else print('NO');"
```

If you want to add more options you can do like this

```
python3 -c "options={'Y': 'Yes', 'N': 'No', 'O': 'Other'}; ans=input('Y/N/O?'); print(options.get(ans, 'Undefined'))"
```

The `options` defined here is a dictionary mapping user input to display values

Answer (score 1):

`python3 -c "ans=input('Y/N?'); print('YES') if ans == 'Y' else print('NO')"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary expression:

`python3 -c "ans=input('Y/N?'); print('YES' if ans == 'Y' else 'NO')"`